# strange Access LEFT JOIN results in duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

```
table m:
ID
1
2
3
4

table y:
id name
1  Lu
2  Os
3  It
3  Ri

SELECT m.id, y.*
FROM my as m
LEFT JOIN your as y ON my.id = y.mID
```

I would like to have each one result from `m` joined with `y` but it returns

```
1 Lu
2 Os
3 It
3 Ri
4
```

Why there are 3, 3 duplicates? I hoped for result like 1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 0):

You have two values in table y with ID 3, This makes it return twice the ID 3. And you don't have any match for id 4, making it return null for that one:

```
ID  NAME
1   Lu
2   Os
3   It
3   Ri
4   (null)
```

If you want it to be 1,2,3,4 you would have to update the 3  Ri in table y to 4 Ri.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, but the only thing strange about the query results is your expectation of what they should be. Access is treating that query just like any other SQL database would (or, at least, any other SQL database that *I've* dealt with).

If you really want only 4 rows returned then you'll need to use an aggregation query, something like this

```sql
SELECT m.id, MIN(y.name) AS [name]
  FROM my as m
  LEFT JOIN 
  your as y 
    ON m.id = y.mID
GROUP BY m.id
```